# Retrieving DATA from EXCEL which is in Russian Language & saving it in DBF format (VFP)

Tags: excel, visual-foxpro

I want to retrieve DATA from EXCEL which is in Russian Language & saving it in DBF format . What I want that while printing I will use that same font & print data, But when I append from XLS , CSV or Delimited File into DBF file all Character becomes ???????

Answer (score 1):

The Excel file very likely has data in [Unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode). The DBF format does not natively support Unicode characters, so the conversion process would very likely change them to the "closest" ANSI character, which will fail for many/most characters. In order to preserve the characters, you would likely need to write your own export/import utility to read the Unicode data and then write it to the DBF without a Unicode to ANSI conversion.